# How to identify the object with in the HTML using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

Might be a bit of an edge use case, but I need to identify and then click on an object on a login page. The page itself is dynamically generated and all of the (4) buttons are labeled as such:

```
button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text jss100" tabindex="0" type="button">
```

With the full breakdown of the button I'm trying to click being:

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text jss100" tabindex="0" type="button"><span class="MuiButton-label"><div class="MuiBox-root jss129 jss101 jss128" params="[object Object]"><div class="MuiBox-root jss131 jss104 jss130"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M21 6h-2v9H6v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h11l4 4V7c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zm-4 6V3c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H3c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v14l4-4h10c.55 0 1-.45 1-1z"></path></svg></div><div class="MuiBox-root jss133 jss107 jss132">Q&A</div></div><div class="MuiBox-root jss135 jss107 jss134">Security Questions</div></span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
```

I've tried mapping the XPATH, using CSS Selectors, trying to find the strings of text embedded in in the button, and even trying to find the SVG by using the following:

```
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH , value = '//path[@d="
```

Any ideas how I can get Selenium to identify this object without any static identifiers?

Here's everything I've got so far:

```
#I know most of these are extraneous references :/
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import sys

url = 'https://***.com'
chrome_driver_path = '/Users/***/chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
)

with webdriver as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get(url)
    wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))

    inputUsername = driver.find_element_by_id("loginID")
    inputPassword = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
    findLoginButton = driver.find_element_by_id("submit-button")

    inputUsername.send_keys('[username]')
    inputPassword.send_keys('[password]')
    findLoginButton.click()
    
    # element1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.MuiBox-root.jss135.jss107.jss134")
    # wait.until(presence_of_element_located(element1))
    # element1.click()

    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH , value = '//path[@d="M21 6h-2v9H6v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h11l4 4V7c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zm-4 6V3c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H3c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v14l4-4h10c.55 0 1-.45 1-1z"]')
    #CSS_SELECTOR,value="#root > div > div > ^MuiBox-root^ > ^MuiBox-root^ > form > div > div.MuiCollapse-container.MuiCollapse-entered > div > div > div > button:nth-child(5)]")
    #find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/button[4]").click()

    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and the innerText ***Security Questions***:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'MuiButtonBase-root')]/span[@class='MuiButton-label']//div[text()='Security Questions']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and the innerText ***Q&A***:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'MuiButtonBase-root')]/span[@class='MuiButton-label']//div[text()='Q&A']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: In both cases, the program still threw a timeout exception:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/***.py", line 49, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'MuiButtonBase-root')]/span[@class='MuiButton-label']//div[text()='Security Questions']"))).click()
  File "/***/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:`

Comment: Seems the element can't be located within the DOM. Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your locator is wrong, which is why your element isn't being found.

Try this:

`driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.//div, 'Security Questions')]")`

This Xpath will return a button element that contains a div with the text "Security Questions."